# Showing categories with scope in tabs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I'm trying to have some tabs, in which I would like to show a different category of "Food" in each of them.

I have a Model "Categories", with a `:name` attribute, and I have a model "Foods" with a `:category_id` attribute.

Model Asociations are: Food has_one category, and Categories has_many foods.

I created a scope in my model :by_category:

```
scope :by_category, -> category {where(category_id: category).reverse_order}
```

And I created a by_category method in my controller:

```
  def by_category
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @foods = Food.by_category(params[:category_id])
  end
```

After this, I seeded my db with 7 categories.

So, I just want to show a different category in each tab in my view, but nothing shows up (my tabs are empty), although I created some foods.

#### In my view

```
<ul class="accordion-tabs">
  <li>
     <% @foods.by_category(1).each do |food| %>
      <p><%= food.name %><%= food.ingredients %></p>
     <% end %>
  </li>
  <li>
     <% @foods.by_category(2).each do |food| %>
      <p><%= food.name %><%= food.ingredients %></p>
     <% end %>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

#### Update

My seeds are:

```
SUSHI_CATEGORIES.each do |category_name|
    Category.create(name: category_name, description: "Esto es una categoria")
puts "Categoria creada"
end

Food.create(name: "Bandeja Addict", ingredients: "La mejor bandeja de addict, te traemos ahora con salmon y pepino", addict_food_image: "http://www.monstersushi.com/images/slides/sushi20.jpg")
puts "Bandeja Addict creada"
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you run rake db:seed ?

Comment: Yes I did...I don't know why its not working

Comment: How are you writing your seeds, using Fixtures in some .yml files ?

Comment: Nope, see updated question please

Comment: @Gibson what is SUSHI_CATEGORIES?

Comment: It's a constant with an Array of categories. I fixed it by passing the params in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by passing the params in the view in each tab:

```
 <% @foods.by_category(params[3]).each do |food| %>
    <%= render "food_card" %>
 <% end %>
```